# reason for error message type was not found or was not a compile time constant: PodLayoutManager

Tags: actionscript-3

In my flex code there is an error message : type was not found or was not a compile time constant:PodLayoutManager what will be the reason for these error message?I am using flashbuilder 4 for scripting

............UPDATE.......................

For this Dash board application I have imported the following packages

```
        import com.esria.samples.dashboard.events.LayoutChangeEvent;
        import com.esria.samples.dashboard.managers.PodLayoutManager;
        import com.esria.samples.dashboard.managers.StateManager;
        import com.esria.samples.dashboard.view.ChartContent;
        import com.esria.samples.dashboard.view.FormContent;
        import com.esria.samples.dashboard.view.ListContent;
        import com.esria.samples.dashboard.view.PieChartContent;
        import com.esria.samples.dashboard.view.Pod;
        import com.esria.samples.dashboard.view.PodContentBase;
        import com.esria.samples.dashboard.managers.*;
        import spark.components.NavigatorContent;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.events.IndexChangedEvent;
        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;
```

............UPDATE.......................

Now the above problem is solved.But while running this code the problem window shows type was not found or was not a compile time constant:managers

Answer (score 1):

It means you haven't import the package that contains PodLayoutManager.

`import com.esria.samples.dashboard.managers.*;`

In your actionscript settings you need to include the base location of the package (in this case the base location is the com folder). If the com folder is located at `c:\libs\com\.......` your actionscript settings must include a path to `c:\libs\`

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: from where we can find this setting?

Comment: Goto document Publish settings, then actionscript, then actionscript 3 settings

Comment: Is this path is in properties of adobe flash builder 4?

Answer (score 0):

Check your folder structure again and make sure when you traverse the folders  com/esria/samples/dashboard/managers/

There is a PodLayoutManager class.
Also recheck that the imports and code were done properly in the PodLayoutManager class as well.

The folder organization should be just like in the [example](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/devnet/dashboard/srcview/index.html).